# How can I get 'next-error' to copy the line causing the error into the kill-ring?

Tags: elisp

I tried running

```
(list (next-error) 
      (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
```

immediately after <kbd>M-x compile</kbd>

But it pushes the current line to the kill ring, not the line where the error was found...

If so how do I make emacs wait for `(next-error)` to complete before continuing with the next command?

Answer (score 0):

This little bit of advice will copy the line specified by the error into the kill ring:

```
(defadvice compilation-goto-locus (after next-error-copy-offending-line activate)
  (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))
```

If you decided you wanted to grab the error message, you could use this:

```
(progn
  (next-error)
  (with-current-buffer next-error-last-buffer
    (kill-ring-save (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position))))
```

Comment: @fakedrake Then the problem isn't the order, it's the functionality of `next-error` - I assume you want to copy the offending line...

Comment: @fakedrake The answer has been updated to copy the offending line.

Comment: i need the offending line in the source file not in the compilation buffer in case it is'nt clear

Comment: @fakedrake I updated your question to actually be what you're asking, and updated the answer appropriately.